Where i can set these propeties Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=True in WCF custom transport screen in receive location of BizTalk application
Where I can set these properties Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=True in WCF custom transport screen in receive location of BizTalk application.
I am using SQL database to polling data in one receive location in BizTalk application.
Now SQL team asked to use below
    Encrypt=yes;
    TrustServerCertificate=True;.

In all SQL instance they going to enforce the encryption at their end. Where I can add these properties in the receive location? I Can see encrypt under tab Binding tab. but where I can add TrustServerCertificate=True..?

I don't think you can.
What you have to do is get the public key of the certificate and install it in Trusted Root Certification Authorities, Certificates for the BizTalk Host User on the BizTalk server.

Hi dIJKGRAFFF  ..Is there any chance it will work if i change only Encrypt=yes; in the WCF transport property for that receive location alone.

@bigB If the certificate is issued in such a way that .Net on the BizTalk server trusts it, then yes, it would work.  Otherwise you have to add it to the certificate store on the server so it is trusted.
